# Days of the Week

Tags: code-golf, date

Create a function that accepts a list of dates (unsorted with possible duplicates) and returns the days of the week in one of the following formats:

- A format similar to `MTWTFSS` or `SMTWTFS` (i.e. beginning with Monday or Sunday), with non-days replaced by an underscore `_`, illustrated below.
- `WEEKDAY` if all the dates are between Monday to Friday (i.e. Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday must all be present, no other days)
- `WEEKEND` if all the dates are on Saturday or Sunday (i.e. Saturday and Sunday must both be present, no other days)
- `ALLWEEK` if all the dates are on all days of the week!

Assume the list of dates to be in your language's date data type (e.g. `List<LocalDate>` for Java), else the ISO date string `"YYYY-MM-DD"`. **Addition: After looking at [05AB1E's entry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230848/21697), I'm now also inclined to accept 'the most convenient representation', but please explain clearly why this would be used in lieu of the original rules. I just don't want to open the flood gates here...**

If it helps, you can further assume that all dates are within an arbitrary calendar non-leap-year.

Examples:

| Input | Output (starting Monday) | Output (starting Sunday) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `["2021-06-21"]` | `M______` | `_M_____` |
| `["2021-06-21", "2021-06-28"]` | `M______` | `_M_____` |
| `["2021-06-22", "2021-06-22"]` | `_T_____` | `__T____` |
| `["2021-06-23", "2021-07-16"]` | `__W_F__` | `___W_F_` |
| `["2021-06-27", "2021-07-02", "2021-05-01"]` | `____FSS` | `S____FS` |
| `["2021-06-21", "2021-06-22", "2021-06-23", "2021-06-24", "2021-06-25"]` | `WEEKDAY` | `WEEKDAY` |
| `["2021-06-27", "2021-06-26", "2021-06-27"]` | `WEEKEND` | `WEEKEND` |
| `["2021-06-21", "2021-06-23", "2021-06-22", "2021-06-26", "2021-06-25", "2021-06-24", "2021-06-27"]` | `ALLWEEK` | `ALLWEEK` |

Winning Criteria: Shortest code wins.

Comment: can we take an array of Date objects in javascript. or is it necessary to take input as string

Comment: @AndrewTheCodegolfer added...

Comment: @EliteDaMyth eh sure, just mention it in your answer what the function input type is, I've quickly added a Java example.

Comment: Can we output in lowercase?

Comment: Are we allowed to take the date as a list `[dd,mm,yyyy]` (i.e. `[21,6,2021]`)? My language of choice doesn't have date objects, but mandatory using `"YYYY-MM-DD"` seems a bit distractive of the core of the challenge if I just convert it to a `[21,6,2021]` anyway..

Comment: `["2021-06-21"]` is just a single Monday. So it would seem that all the given dates are weekdays. Why isn't the expected result `WEEKDAY`?

Comment: @Shaggy sorry nope, output must be in uppercase.

Comment: @Adám from the example, `WEEKDAY` is the output if it consists of Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday. I thought it'll be clear compared to the initial explanation, which does sound a bit ambiguous. I've since fixed the initial explanation, thanks!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen after some deliberation, I've decided to make an exception. :) Have clarified this on my question too...

Comment: I deduce from the 05AB1E's answer that a full program is admissible too, not only a function? It's the default on the site anyway..

Comment: @Kaddath eh that's fine too... generally just 'something' that takes an input and returns an output. If your program takes input arguments and display the output on the console, I guess that's output 'returned' as well...

Comment: I suspect that the description is still not what you intended.  It says "ONE of the following formats", without completely specifying which. As currently written, either WEEKDAY or MTWTF__ would be acceptable outputs in the case of the 5th example.  I suspect you want WEEKDAY in this case, but that is not what is written.

Comment: @aeh5040 the fifth example is Friday, Saturday, Sunday, so you should only output the letters `F`, `S`, `S`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the 6th example.

Comment: @aeh5040 the points should be read in increasing order of importance, i.e. the `ALLWEEK` supercedes `WEEKEND` or `WEEKDAY`, which in turn supercedes the day-specific base format. The examples imply that too... otherwise for the sixth example I'll happy put one of the accept output to be `MTWTF__`, which wouldn't be in the original question. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 71 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Not happy with this first pass; need to try a few different approaches to see if I can get it down any smaller. <s>Outputs in lowercase, pending confirmation.</s> +3 bytes for the unnecessary requirement of uppercase output.

```
£ÐX eÃÍâ
`³ekÜü³ekÀAa¥³ekmtwtfs`qi o£øY ?X:'_ÃfÏg[Ue5õ)60¥U¬Ô7¥UÊ1]ÃÎu
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=o9BYIGXDzeIKYLNla9z8s2VrwEFhpbNla4ltdHd0ZnNgcWkgb6P4WSA/WDonX8Nmz2dbVWU19Sk2MKVVrNQ3pVXKMV3DznU&input=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) - includes all test cases

Comment: The string encoding with `s` is very nice. Since you can take a list of native dates as an input, you could move `£ÐX ` to the header to shave off 4 bytes.

Comment: I had contemplated that, @Etheryte, but it felt like cheating to me to workaround the fact that Japt can't natively handle date objects as input. Also, the first line would then become `me Íâ` and I'd need a `V` in from of the `ø` in the last `map` so it would only save 2 bytes.

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>93</s> 92 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
'_7×sε`UD3‹©12*+>₂*T÷®Xα©т%D4÷®т÷©4÷®·(O7%}D.•1ÎÐ³¦•©sèsǝÀÐáÐÙ'sQi'œÙë®¦¦Qi’…Â‚Ž’ëQi’€Ÿ…Â’]u
```

Inputs in the format `[dd,mm,yyyy]`; output format starts at Sunday (`SMTWTFS`).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fPd788PTic1sTQl2MHzXsPLTS0EhL2@5RU5NWyOHth9ZFnNt4aOXFJlUXExDvYhOQXAlmHtqu4W@uWuui96hhkeHhvsMTDm0@tAzIPrSy@PCK4uNzDzccnnB44eEJjxrmFRcHZqofnXx45uHVQH3LDi0LzHzUMPNRw7LDTY8aZh3dC@QcXg0Ra1pzdAdUYmZs6f//0dFGxjpmOkYGRoaxOtGGZjrmEHbsf13dvHzdnMSqSgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXSf/V488PTi89tTQh1MX7UsPPQSkMjLW27R01NWiGHtx9aF3Fu46GVF5tUXUxAvItNQHIlmHlou4a/uWqti96jhkWGh/sOTzi0@dAyIPvQyuLDK4qPzz3ccHjC4YWHJzxqmFdcHJipfnTy4ZmHVwP1LTu0LDDzUcPMRw3LDjc9aph1dC@Qc3g1RKxpzdEdUImZsaX/lfTCdP5HR0cbGeqY6RgZGBnGxuooIHN1oo0sUKWMkKSMUKWMEVKGZjrmyFLmSLpgMkBVOqa4bEW2BslcIxMktimq9ch2mCGxzXH7zRiHjWbYbEGzHWFs7H9d3bx83ZzEqkoA).

**Explanation:**

Since 05AB1E has no Date builtins, we'll have to calculate the *Day of the Week* manually.

The general formula to do this is:

$${\displaystyle h=\left(q+\left\lfloor{\frac{13(m+1)}{5}}\right\rfloor+K+\left\lfloor{\frac{K}{4}}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor{\frac{J}{4}}\right\rfloor-2J\right){\bmod{7}}}$$

Where for the months March through December:

- \$q\$ is the \$day\$ of the month (`[1, 31]`)
- \$m\$ is the 1-indexed \$month\$ (`[3, 12]`)
- \$K\$ is the year of the century (\$year \bmod 100\$)
- \$J\$ is the 0-indexed century (\$\left\lfloor {\frac {year}{100}}\right\rfloor\$)

And for the months January and February:

- \$q\$ is the \$day\$ of the month (`[1, 31]`)
- \$m\$ is the 1-indexed \$month + 12\$ (`[13, 14]`)
- \$K\$ is the year of the century for the previous year (\$(year - 1) \bmod 100\$)
- \$J\$ is the 0-indexed century for the previous year (\$\left\lfloor {\frac {year-1}{100}}\right\rfloor\$)

Resulting in the day of the week \$h\$, where 0 = Saturday, 1 = Sunday, ..., 6 = Friday.
[Source: Zeller's congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence)

The implementation of this formula in the code below is:

```
`UD3‹©12*+>₂*T÷®Xα©т%D4÷®т÷©4÷®·(O7%
```

```python
'_7×        '# Push string "_______"
s            # Swap to get the (implicit) input-list
 ε           # Map over each date:
             #  Determine its day of the week:
  `          #   Push the day, month, and year to the stack
   U         #   Pop and save the year in variable `X`
    D        #   Duplicate the month
     3‹      #   Check if the month is below 3 (Jan. / Feb.),
             #   resulting in 1 or 0 for truthy/falsey respectively
       ©     #   Store this in variable `®` (without popping)
        12*  #   Multiply it by 12 (either 0 or 12)
           + #   And add it to the month
             #   (This first part was to make Jan. / Feb. 13 and 14)
  >          #   Month + 1
   ₂*        #   Multiplied by 26
     T÷      #   Integer-divided by 10
  ®          #   Push month<3 from variable `®` again
   Xα        #   Take the absolute difference with the year
     ©       #   Store this potentially modified year as new `®` (without popping)
      т%     #   mYear modulo-100
  D4÷        #   mYear modulo-100, integer-divided by 4
  ®т÷©4÷     #   mYear integer-divided by 100, and then integer-divided by 4
  ®·(        #   mYear integer-divided by 100, doubled, and then made negative
  O          #   Take the sum of all values on the stack
   7%        #   And then take modulo-7 to complete the formula, resulting in 0 for
             #   Saturday, 1 for Sunday, and [2, 6] for [Monday, Friday]
}D           # After the map: duplicate the list of integers
  .•1ÎÐ³¦•   # Push compressed string "ssmtwtf"
          ©  # Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
  s          # Swap so the duplicated list of integers is at the top
   è         # Index each into this string
    s        # Swap so the list of integers is at the top again
     ǝ       # Insert the characters at these indices inside the "_______" string
      À      # Rotate it once towards the left
Ð            # Triplicate this result
 á           # Only leave the letters of the top copy
  Ð          # Triplicate that as well
   „ssQi    '# Pop one copy, and if it's equal to "ss":
      'œÙ   '#  Push dictionary string "weekend"
    ë®¦¦Qi   # Else-if it's equal to `®` minus its first two characters ("mtwtf"):
      ’…Â‚Ž’ #  Push dictionary string "weekday"
    ëQi      # Else-if the string remained the same after only leaving letters:
      ’€Ÿ…Â’ #  Push dictionary string "allweek"
    ]        # Close all if-else statements
     u       # Uppercase the result
             # (after which this is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to use the dictionary?* and *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `.•1ÎÐ³¦•` is `"ssmtwtf"`; `'œÙ` is `"weekend"`; `’…Â‚Ž’` is `"weekday"`; and `’€Ÿ…Â’` is `"allweek"`.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 119 bytes

Expects a list of `Date` objects. Uses the `SMTWTFS` format.

```javascript
a=>a.map(d=>a|=1<<d.getDay())|a-127?a-62?a-65?'SMTWTFS'.replace(/./g,(c,i)=>a>>i&1?c:'_'):'WEEKEND':'WEEKDAY':'ALLWEEK'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZJBa4MwGIbv/orQwxLBpCZOHV1VCrrLul1aKKOU8RGjczgVlY1B/7tTemhtWZtD@J48JO97yCd8QyPrrGppUcaqS7wOPB/YF1Qk7oe9x@fzmKWqDeGX6PoeKBduANQRw2YHePWy3qyfVpjVqspBKjJl09Qg0sj0/r7vZ3c8kDP8jvUZ3kTRc/Qa4sMULt76abFcDoC7x62G0HYiTMGp6VDBJzvj/MRAR3q48GLkxYW3jt6l3Lnw7qk3T16zqXmrzTjbGtH9iOxruT05I3Jv5FpXWjhnuf936lO0ncaSso5AfhBAno9kWTRlrlhepiQhhy/RDKJQPyiEVpFGH1b3Bw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>223</s> <s>216</s> <s>204</s> <s>200</s> <s>190</s> 186 bytes

Straight forward implementation with `datetime` functions, no fancy string compression.

Saved some bytes exploiting a `dict` for the special cases.

*-4 bytes thanx to Kateba*

```python
from datetime import*
m='MTWTFSS'
def f(x,y='_'*7):
 for z in x:i=date.fromisoformat(z).weekday();y=y[:i]+m[i]+y[i+1:]
 return{y:y,m:'ALLWEEK','MTWTF__':'WEEKDAY','_____SS':'WEEKEND'}[y]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZFfa4MwFMWfzacIfYm2Wvyz6sjwoVD3sm4vLZQRRGRGFkZU0ow1HfvsLqEPrcLcfQic8@PecyCdku9tE/V9LVoOq1JSyTiFjHetkHPAU/S8P@wfdzsEKlrD2j65KkUFmicOBrBuBTxD1sATZqlZXpoz7NhqwEtpn53lF6UfVals50GlimCWLzjRjyJsEeAcQEHlp2i@FVYux2i93R6y7Am5l9iiQBgZY7N@1V5hRle5eNnLBv0QlfemxVt5pKYIARaZhX4YeH7shcEsd0eGC6/qfozDAQ7HOLrixAviMU5usX9za@X5/zQZBkcDdTdQq4lUreKBSqZTo4kO8Sj170Y6BFg5BlYnWCPt2jZ/4Tj9Lw)

Comment: [-4 bytes](https://tio.run/##hZFfa4MwFMWfzacIfYm2Wvyz6sjwoVD3sm4vLZQRRGRGFkZU0ow1HfvsLqEPrcLcfQic8@PecyCdku9tE/V9LVoOq1JSyTiFjHetkHPAU/S8P@wfdzsEKlrD2j65KkUFmicOBrBuBTxD1sATZqlZXpoz7NhqwEtpn53lF6UfVals50GlimCWLzjRjyJsEeAcQEHlp2i@FVYux2i93R6y7Am5l9iiQBgZY7N@1V5hRle5eNnLBv0QlfemxVt5pKYIARaZhX4YeH7shcEsd0eGC6/qfozDAQ7HOLrixAviMU5usX9za@X5/zQZBkcDdTdQq4lUreKBSqZTo4kO8Sj170Y6BFg5BlYnWCPt2jZ/4Tj9Lw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>133</s> 132 bytes

```php
for($w=SMTWTFS,$r=_______;$d=$argv[++$i];)$r[$j=$d->format(w)]=$w[$j];echo$r==$w?ALLWEEK:$r==_MTWTF_?WEEKDAY:$r==S_____S?WEEKEND:$r;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVPBboJAFLzzFS9kD5BCVGy1kaIhSi@l7QGMaSghFLZFE4EsqE2afjt9rLRaExtjymHZmd15bx5h8iSvbkZ5kguvGZN0ErK3tXdxQYK5r8tbVO/BgDgsaRAxii9pdyDrVS0kG8O5d2furaMQZgTbRyex8VOQ12MeWRgkVoeoWYaltJF9g2yQ9HUaJRlKEY5M255Z1t2ghgGvGoxqYmI@cc7h1R3OWQ8T5PSqloMoCKgF13JcGJuO5QwEURfqyWgYJZInAHjiKl0VNAapiNg8LyENl1QWFRC1ttZR2z1V64i@curNfXR9sk47QKfqujvUVzu9k3X9fV17r/uV2j53Wu2YM0SXv9DVOT4R9Q7OzvPZ/cN178Dn8Rl4dx/CAvgPLX@glVaL0YKWME9j@g7rkBVIYiYwK6ReHqa2rSPFryY0jCkbQJSla8pKKDMeKMheFjQqa@W5@fvuYI7dqWnD@HFiNdX@J5QeaoeEKVht2CRTaVJpDJtYKk0ktwRm0keV31jbRvM5xSh@VtXu4@@2/S8)

Uses the script arguments array converted to `DateTime` objects (1-indexed), uses the `SMTWTFS` format.

First version with the dict exploit like in [movatica's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230878/90841), but still looking how to shorten it.

**EDIT:** saved 1 byte with ternary operators

Comment: Save some bytes by doing $d=$argv[++$i]->format(w), and no need to create $j.

Comment: @GuillermoPhillips I tried things like this, unfortunately it doesn't work, first because the index is falsey for sunday (`"0"`) and that would stop the loop, second because when it reaches the end of the array, `->format` throws an error on `NULL` and there's no input.. I'm still searching

Comment: *output (not input)

Comment: Understood - now I've actually tried it! It's a shame. I notice that ALLWEEK, WEEKEND and  WEEKDAY are all seven characters. Thinking about how to run with that, hmm.

Comment: @GuillermoPhillips yeah, but actually that was a disadvantage when I tried to golf the code, because 7 is short, so all solutions I thought of ended longer than having the litteral strings in there

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 155 bytes

```perl
$o="_"x7;join("",map{strftime"%F%w%A",0,0,0,$_,0,0}0..6e4)=~/$_(.)(.)/,substr$o,$1,1,$2for@F;$_={_MTWTF_,WEEKDAY,S_____S,WEEKEND,SMTWTFS,ALLWEEK}->{$o}||$o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1tS8MwFIW/@yskpLDBTZekSyuMioW1IG4qZDD9FCZ0UNmW0tYX6OpPN7ZFl4FNAvfkuZxz8rTYCWOwDpFCn8HsVWeHEUKw3@R1WRXbKtunyEmcDydCQPuLVTca6rp@Oh2HXxOsRu64fRMo315aE9aAGTDAfKuLm2SGVVir5Wq9ShSs4/huHj2DVN2R/T@@n4Ps9xKixaJDDbmusW6OR6yN4ZQzQn3C2YWVlyd5ZSm3lFvq/dKAMN/S4ETpn00QOlxxlutZObVS/M9tpW9lMJjrDVac2cRgW/Ct8yrTh9KQTb4zZPkuXEbb@fggb59@AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 125 bytes

```ruby
f=->l{i=0;l.map{|d|i|=2**d.wday};{i=>(0..6).map{|a|i[a]>0?'SMTWTFS'[a]:?_}*'',62=>'WEEKDAY',65=>"WEEKEND",127=>"ALLWEEK"}[i]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZJda4MwFIbv/RUhN2lFQ4wzlhUtBd3Nut20UIZIyZqUCd3m/GCUxt/uImO0VtbeBJ73gbwHzinq10Pb7gI73B@zgEz3@J3nRyVUpgJqmgJ/C35optqFI4IxG/96rrKEpyGZoeXTar16WCKN97NNYyJkMRqEaB3Hj9H8RZMXhLCj@DmClkN9jfPFoktgk2Rp0xbyq84KCZDglURGYgCQQEqoYxNmUwem1mVigRNNBp72PB149@R922ED7597cvabZ5Nb0/S73R7d9ci71quJ9ci/0etemYJd9P4/k24xUiz59g2IT6AqWVZbXkqlm/O6KsEu@Yu6MwD6TvTGFIj0i3NelHLUBeMmNeSHaH8A)

Takes a list of `Date`s and outputs in the `SMTWTFS` format.
Abuses Ruby's integer subscriptions to get a (sort of) boolean array.

I copied the dict exploit of the python answer, it works well :)